Webgl shadows implemetation trouble
I wanna implement shadows example from  webgl2fundamentals
also i a aware of framebuffer principe a have already working implementation of mirror projection.
I have trouble with shadows examples...
I always get black collor or error logs :
GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Feedback loop formed between Framebuffer and active Texture.

My scene have two cubes. One floor and myTextCube1 on top.
object.FBO.FB.texture comes from "makeFBO()".
This is most important code from draw function:
DRAWER:
App.operation.draws.cube = function(object, ray) {
    var lighting = true;
    var localLooper = 0;

    mat4.identity(object.mvMatrix);
    this.mvPushMatrix(object.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrixStack);

     
        if(App.camera.FirstPersonController == true) {
            camera.setCamera(object)
        } else if(App.camera.SceneController == true) {
            camera.setSceneCamera(object)
        }

        mat4.translate(object.mvMatrix, object.mvMatrix, object.position.worldLocation);
        if(raycaster.checkingProcedureCalc && typeof ray === 'undefined') raycaster.checkingProcedureCalc(object);

        mat4.rotate(object.mvMatrix, object.mvMatrix, degToRad(object.rotation.rx), object.rotation.getRotDirX());
        mat4.rotate(object.mvMatrix, object.mvMatrix, degToRad(object.rotation.ry), object.rotation.getRotDirY());
        mat4.rotate(object.mvMatrix, object.mvMatrix, degToRad(object.rotation.rz), object.rotation.getRotDirZ());

    // V
    if(object.vertexPositionBuffer) {
        world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexPositionBuffer);
        if(object.geometry.dynamicBuffer == true) {
            world.GL.gl.bufferData(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.geometry.vertices, world.GL.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }
        world.GL.gl.vertexAttribPointer(object.shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, object.vertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, world.GL.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        world.GL.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(object.shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);
        localLooper = localLooper + 1;
    }

    // C
    if(object.vertexColorBuffer) {
        world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexColorBuffer);
        world.GL.gl.vertexAttribPointer(object.shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute, object.vertexColorBuffer.itemSize, world.GL.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        world.GL.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(object.shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);
        localLooper = localLooper + 1;
    }

    // L
    if(lighting && object.shaderProgram.useLightingUniform) {
        world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.useLightingUniform, lighting);
        /* Set the normals */
        if(object.vertexNormalBuffer) {
            world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexNormalBuffer);
            world.GL.gl.vertexAttribPointer(object.shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, object.vertexNormalBuffer.itemSize, world.GL.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            world.GL.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(object.shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute);
            localLooper = localLooper + 1;
        }
        /* Set the ambient light */
        if(object.shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform) {
            if(E('ambLightR')) {
                world.GL.gl.uniform3f(
                    object.shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform,
                    parseFloat(E('ambLightR').getAttribute('value')),
                    parseFloat(E('ambLightG').getAttribute('value')),
                    parseFloat(E('ambLightB').getAttribute('value'))
                );
                // console.log("LIGHTS UNIFORM AMB  B = ", parseFloat(E('ambLightB').value) )
            } else {
                // object.LightsData.ambientLight
                world.GL.gl.uniform3f(object.shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform, object.LightsData.ambientLight.r, object.LightsData.ambientLight.g, object.LightsData.ambientLight.b);
            }
        }

        /* Directional light */
        if(object.shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform) {
            if(E('dirLightR')) {
                world.GL.gl.uniform3f(
                    object.shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform,
                    parseFloat(E('dirLightR').getAttribute('value')),
                    parseFloat(E('dirLightG').getAttribute('value')),
                    parseFloat(E('dirLightB').getAttribute('value'))
                );
            } else {
                //console.log('TEST')
                world.GL.gl.uniform3f(object.shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform, object.LightsData.directionLight.R(), object.LightsData.directionLight.G(), object.LightsData.directionLight.B());
            }
        }

        /* Normalize the direction */
        var lightingDirection = null;

        if(object.shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform) {
            if(E('dirX') && E('dirY') && E('dirZ')) {
                // console.log("LIGHTS UNIFORM AMB  B = ",  E('dirZ').value )
                lightingDirection = [degToRad(parseFloat(E('dirX').getAttribute('value'))), degToRad(parseFloat(E('dirY').getAttribute('value'))), degToRad(parseFloat(E('dirZ').getAttribute('value')))];
            } else {
                lightingDirection = [object.LightsData.lightingDirection.r, object.LightsData.lightingDirection.g, object.LightsData.lightingDirection.b];
            }

            var adjustedLD = vec3.create();
            vec3.normalize(adjustedLD, lightingDirection);
            vec3.scale(adjustedLD, adjustedLD, -1);
            world.GL.gl.uniform3fv(object.shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform, adjustedLD);
        }
    } else {
        if(object.shaderProgram.useLightingUniform) {
            if(object.shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform) {
                world.GL.gl.uniform3f(object.shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform, parseFloat(0.2), parseFloat(0.2), parseFloat(0.2));
            }
            if(object.shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform) {
                world.GL.gl.uniform3f(object.shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform, parseFloat(1), parseFloat(0), parseFloat(0));
            }
        }
    }

    // T
    if(object.vertexTexCoordBuffer) {
        world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexTexCoordBuffer);

        if(object.geometry.dynamicBuffer == true) {
            world.GL.gl.bufferData(world.GL.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.geometry.texCoords, world.GL.gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        world.GL.gl.vertexAttribPointer(object.shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, object.vertexTexCoordBuffer.itemSize, world.GL.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        world.GL.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(object.shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

      if(object.FBO) {
            // Fbo staff
            // console.log('LOG FBO TEXT ACTIVATE')
            makeFBO2(object, world.GL.gl )
            world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE0);
            world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.FBO.FB.texture);
            world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.u_projectedTexture, 0);
            world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
         // TEST
        } else {
            for(var t = 0;t < object.textures.length;t++) {
                if(object.custom.gl_texture == null) {
                    world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl['TEXTURE' + t]);
                    world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.textures[t]);
                    world.GL.gl.pixelStorei(world.GL.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, false);
                    if(object.texParams.MIPMAP == false) {
                        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, object.texParams.TEXTURE_WRAP_S | world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
                        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, object.texParams.TEXTURE_WRAP_T | world.GL.gl.REPEAT);
                    } else {
                        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, object.texParams.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER | world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
                        world.GL.gl.texParameteri(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, object.texParams.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER | world.GL.gl.LINEAR);
                        world.GL.gl.generateMipmap(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D);
                    }

                    if(world.GL.extTFAnisotropic && object.texParams.ANISOTROPIC == true) {
                        world.GL.gl.texParameterf(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D,
                            world.GL.extTFAnisotropic.TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT,
                            world.GL.MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT);
                    }

                    // console.log('TEST TEX SMAPLER ...' , object.texParams)
                    world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, t);
                    world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.u_projectedTexture, 0);
                } else {
                    object.custom.gl_texture(object, t);
                }
            }
        }
        localLooper = localLooper + 1;
    } else {

        if(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform) {
            world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
        } 
    }


    // Shadows effect
    if(object.shadows && object.shadows.type == 'spot-shadow' && !object.FBO) {

        let textureMatrix = m4.identity();
        textureMatrix = m4.translate(textureMatrix, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        textureMatrix = m4.scale(textureMatrix, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
        textureMatrix = m4.multiply(textureMatrix, object.shadows.lightProjectionMatrix);

        const lightWorldMatrix = m4.lookAt(
            [object.shadows.lightPosition[0], object.shadows.lightPosition[1], object.shadows.lightPosition[2]],
            [object.shadows.lightTarget[0], object.shadows.lightTarget[1], object.shadows.lightTarget[2]], // target
            [object.shadows.orientation[0], object.shadows.orientation[1], object.shadows.orientation[2]], // up
        );
        textureMatrix = m4.multiply(textureMatrix, m4.inverse(lightWorldMatrix));
        const mat = m4.multiply(lightWorldMatrix, m4.inverse(object.shadows.lightProjectionMatrix));
        // draw to the depth texture
        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.u_projectedTexture, false, 0);
 
        world.GL.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(object.shaderProgram.u_textureMatrix, true, textureMatrix);
        // world.GL.gl.uniform3fv(object.shaderProgram.lightWorldPositionLocation, object.shadows.lightPosition);

        // world.GL.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(object.shaderProgram.u_world, true,
        //  m4.translate(object.position.worldLocation[0],
        //      object.position.worldLocation[1],
        //      object.position.worldLocation[2])
        // );
         world.GL.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(object.shaderProgram.u_world, false, mat);
        world.GL.gl.uniform3fv(object.shaderProgram.u_reverseLightDirection, lightWorldMatrix.slice(8, 11));
        world.GL.gl.uniform1f(object.shaderProgram.u_bias, object.shadows.bias);

        // world.GL.gl.uniform1f(object.shaderProgram.shininessLocation, object.shadows.shininess);

        // test  
        //  IF I FORCE FBO
        //  GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Feedback loop formed between Framebuffer and active Texture.

        if (App.GLOBAL && App.GLOBAL.deepTexture && !object.FBO) {
            world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
            world.GL.gl.activeTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE0);
            world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, App.GLOBAL.deepTexture);
            world.GL.gl.uniform1i(object.shaderProgram.u_projectedTexture, 0);
        }


    } 
    world.GL.gl.bindBuffer(world.GL.gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vertexIndexBuffer);
    world.setMatrixUniforms(object, this.pMatrix, object.mvMatrix);

    if(object.vertexNormalBuffer && object.shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform) {
        var normalMatrix = mat3.create();
        mat3.normalFromMat4(normalMatrix, object.mvMatrix);
        mat3.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
        world.GL.gl.uniformMatrix3fv(object.shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform, false, normalMatrix);
    }

    // world.disableUnusedAttr(world.GL.gl, localLooper);
    // FIX FOR MOBILE - from white cube to normal texture view , good
    world.disableUnusedAttr(world.GL.gl, 4);

    if(object.glBlend.blendEnabled == true) {
        if(!world.GL.gl.isEnabled(world.GL.gl.BLEND)) {
            world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.BLEND);
        }
        world.GL.gl.blendFunc(world.GL.gl[object.glBlend.blendParamSrc], world.GL.gl[object.glBlend.blendParamDest]);
    } else {
        world.GL.gl.disable(world.GL.gl.BLEND);
        world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.CULL_FACE);
        world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    }

    world.GL.gl.drawElements(world.GL.gl[object.glDrawElements.mode], object.glDrawElements.numberOfIndicesRender, world.GL.gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    this.mvPopMatrix(object.mvMatrix, this.mvMatrixStack);
};

export const makeFBO2 = (gl, o) => {
    if(typeof o === 'undefined') {
        var o = {width: 512,    height: 512};
    }
    // console.log('FBO FOR SHADOW TEST');
    var error = function() {console.log('Error in creating FBO!'); return null;}

    var gl = world.GL.gl;
    const checkerboardTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, checkerboardTexture);
    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,
        0,                // mip level
        gl.LUMINANCE,     // internal format
        8,                // width
        8,                // height
        0,                // border
        gl.LUMINANCE,     // format
        gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
        new Uint8Array([  // data
            0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
            0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
            0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
            0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
            0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
            0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
            0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC,
            0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xFF,
        ]));
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

    const depthTexture = gl.createTexture();
    const depthTextureSize = 512;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
    gl.texImage2D(
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,      // target
        0,                  // mip level
        gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, // internal format
        depthTextureSize,   // width
        depthTextureSize,   // height
        0,                  // border
        gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, // format
        gl.FLOAT,           // type
        null);              // data
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    const depthFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, depthFramebuffer);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(
        gl.FRAMEBUFFER,       // target
        gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,  // attachment point
        gl.TEXTURE_2D,        // texture target
        depthTexture,         // texture
        0);                   // mip level

    //  world.GL.gl.bindFramebuffer(world.GL.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, depthFramebuffer);
    // world.GL.gl.bindTexture(world.GL.gl.TEXTURE_2D, checkerboardTexture);
   //   world.GL.gl.viewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // world.GL.gl.clear(world.GL.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | world.GL.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // ------------------------------
    //
        // Unbind the buffer object
        // gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        // gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
        // gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, null);
    //
    return [depthFramebuffer, depthTexture];
}

And also importan part of code is render:
App.operation.reDrawGlobal = function(time) {
    modifyLooper(0);
    if(App.offScreenCanvas == false) reDrawID = requestAnimationFrame(App.operation.reDrawGlobal);

    world.renderPerspective();
    for(var t = 0;t < App.updateBeforeDraw.length;t++) {App.updateBeforeDraw[t].UPDATE()}
    // reset to zero
    physicsLooper = 0;

    // Must be override for performance 
    // - non FBO and FBO option draw coroutine

    // hc 512x512
    // Important camera setup must be in the first place in exe order!
    // Before FB bind
    if(world.FBOS.length > 0) {
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.pitchMemo = matrixEngine.Events.camera.pitch;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.yawMemo = matrixEngine.Events.camera.yaw;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.xPosMemo = matrixEngine.Events.camera.xPos;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.zPosMemo = matrixEngine.Events.camera.zPos;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.yPosMemo = matrixEngine.Events.camera.yPos;
    }

    // Multi FB
    for(var fbindex = 0;fbindex < world.FBOS.length;fbindex++) {
        // save samera pos
        // if (typeof world.FBOS[fbindex].settings.xPosMemo === 'undefined') {
        // setup by custom params
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.xPos = world.FBOS[fbindex].settings.cameraX;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.yPos = world.FBOS[fbindex].settings.cameraY;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.zPos = world.FBOS[fbindex].settings.cameraZ;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.pitch = world.FBOS[fbindex].settings.pitch;
        matrixEngine.Events.camera.yaw = world.FBOS[fbindex].settings.yaw;

        world.GL.gl.bindFramebuffer(world.GL.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, world.FBOS[fbindex].FB);

        world.GL.gl.viewport(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
        world.GL.gl.clearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.4, 1.0);
        world.GL.gl.clear(world.GL.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | world.GL.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        // test
        world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.CULL_FACE);
        world.GL.gl.disable(world.GL.gl.BLEND);
        world.GL.gl.depthMask(true);

        // - draw all `non fbo` and `no blend`
        while(looper <= world.contentList.length - 1) {
            if(world.contentList[looper].visible === true &&
                !world.contentList[looper].FBO &&
                world.contentList[looper].glBlend.blendEnabled == false) {
                if('triangle' == world.contentList[looper].type) {
                    world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                    world.drawTriangle(world.contentList[looper], 'noray');
                } else if('cube' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                    'cubeTex' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                    'cubeLightTex' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                    'cubeMap' == world.contentList[looper].type) {

                    // origin - test second shaderprogram
                    // world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                    // world.bufferCube(world.contentList[looper]);
                    // world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgramColor);
                    // world.drawCube(world.contentList[looper], 'noray');
                    // console.log('---------- --------- -------')
                    // test
                    // world.bufferCube(world.contentList[looper]);
                    world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                    world.drawCube(world.contentList[looper], 'noray');

                    // world.contentList[looper].activateTexture()
                } 
            }
            modifyLooper(looper + 1);
        }
        modifyLooper(0);



        // maybe no need here
        world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.BLEND);
        world.GL.gl.depthMask(false);

        // all non FBO but blended
        while(looper <= world.contentList.length - 1) {
            if(world.contentList[looper].visible === true &&
                !world.contentList[looper].FBO &&
                world.contentList[looper].glBlend.blendEnabled == true) {
                if('triangle' == world.contentList[looper].type) {
                    world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                    world.drawTriangle(world.contentList[looper], 'noray')
                }  else if('cube' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                    'cubeTex' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                    'cubeLightTex' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                    'cubeMap' == world.contentList[looper].type) {
                    world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                    world.drawCube(world.contentList[looper], 'noray');
                }  
            }
            modifyLooper(looper + 1);
        }

        modifyLooper(0);

        world.GL.gl.depthMask(true);

        // Back to drawing on the main color buffer!
        world.GL.gl.bindFramebuffer(world.GL.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
        // Multi FBO camera view works but obj seq speed up - probably because OSC !! must be fixed

        // Reset camera
        if(typeof world.FBOS[0] !== 'undefined') {
            matrixEngine.Events.camera.zPos = matrixEngine.Events.camera.zPosMemo;
            matrixEngine.Events.camera.xPos = matrixEngine.Events.camera.xPosMemo;
            matrixEngine.Events.camera.yPos = matrixEngine.Events.camera.yPosMemo;
            matrixEngine.Events.camera.pitch = matrixEngine.Events.camera.pitchMemo;
            matrixEngine.Events.camera.yaw = matrixEngine.Events.camera.yawMemo;
        }
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------


    world.GL.gl.viewport(0, 0, world.GL.gl.canvas.width, world.GL.gl.canvas.height);
    world.GL.gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    world.GL.gl.clear(world.GL.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | world.GL.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw again all
    world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    world.GL.gl.disable(world.GL.gl.BLEND);
    world.GL.gl.depthMask(true);


    // All but no blend
    while(looper <= world.contentList.length - 1) {
        if(world.contentList[looper].visible === true &&
            world.contentList[looper].glBlend.blendEnabled == false) {
            if('triangle' == world.contentList[looper].type) {
                world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                world.drawTriangle(world.contentList[looper]);
                world.animate(world.contentList[looper]);
            } else if('cube' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                'cubeTex' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                'cubeLightTex' == world.contentList[looper].type ||
                'cubeMap' == world.contentList[looper].type) {
                world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                world.drawCube(world.contentList[looper]);
                world.animate(world.contentList[looper]);
            } 
        }
        modifyLooper(looper + 1);
    }

    // world.GL.gl.disable(world.GL.gl.DEPTH_TEST); // TEST ORI
    world.GL.gl.enable(world.GL.gl.BLEND);
    world.GL.gl.depthMask(false);
    modifyLooper(0);

    // all but blend
    while(looper <= world.contentList.length - 1) {
        if(world.contentList[looper].visible === true &&
            world.contentList[looper].glBlend.blendEnabled == true) {
            if('triangle' == world.contentList[looper].type) {
                world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                world.drawTriangle(world.contentList[looper]);
                world.animate(world.contentList[looper]);
            } else if(world.contentList[looper].type.indexOf("custom-") != -1) {
                // interest part - frst time draw func taken from object inself not from world.
                // HERES IS CUBE
                world.GL.gl.useProgram(world.contentList[looper].shaderProgram);
                world.contentList[looper].drawCustom(world.contentList[looper]);
                world.animate(world.contentList[looper]);
                //
            }
        }
        modifyLooper(looper + 1);
    }

    modifyLooper(0);
    world.GL.gl.depthMask(true);

    if(App.raycast) {
        if(secondPass <= 2) {
            raycaster.touchCoordinate.enabled = false;
            secondPass = 0;
        }
    }

    secondPass++;
    physicsLooper = 0;
    updateFPS(1);
 
    }

}

App.operation.CameraPerspective = function() {
    this.GL.gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    this.GL.gl.clear(this.GL.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.GL.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mat4.perspective(this.pMatrix, degToRad(App.camera.viewAngle), this.GL.gl.viewportWidth / this.GL.gl.viewportHeight, App.camera.nearViewpoint, App.camera.farViewpoint);
}

And after all shaders part:
export function generateSpotLightShadowDefinitions() {
    return `// inject generateSpotLightShadowDefinitions
    uniform sampler2D u_projectedTexture;
    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
    in vec2 v_texcoord;
    uniform float u_bias;
    in vec4 v_projectedTexcoord;
    in vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
    in vec3 v_surfaceToView;
    uniform vec4 u_color;
    uniform float u_shininess;
    uniform vec3 u_lightDirection;
    uniform float u_innerLimit;
    uniform float u_outerLimit;
    uniform mat4 u_projection;
    uniform mat4 u_view;
    uniform mat4 u_world;
    uniform mat4 u_textureMatrix;
    uniform vec3 u_reverseLightDirection;
    `;
}

export function generateSpotLightShadowMain() {
    return `
    vec3 normal = normalize(v_normal);
    float light = dot(normal, u_reverseLightDirection);
    vec3 projectedTexcoord = v_projectedTexcoord.xyz / v_projectedTexcoord.w;
    float currentDepth = projectedTexcoord.z + u_bias;

    bool inRange =
            projectedTexcoord.x >= 0.0 &&
            projectedTexcoord.x <= 1.0 &&
            projectedTexcoord.y >= 0.0 &&
            projectedTexcoord.y <= 1.0;
    float projectedDepth = texture(u_projectedTexture, projectedTexcoord.xy).r;
    float shadowLight = (inRange && projectedDepth <= currentDepth) ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    vec4 texColor = texture(u_texture, v_texcoord) * vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    outColor = vec4(texColor.rgb * light * shadowLight , texColor.a);
    `;
}

VS GLSL:
export function getInitVSCubeTexLight() {
  const f = `#version 300 es
  in vec3 aVertexPosition;
  in vec3 aVertexNormal;
  in vec2 aTextureCoord;
  uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
  uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
  uniform mat3 uNMatrix;
  uniform vec3 uAmbientColor;
  uniform vec3 uLightingDirection;
  uniform vec3 uDirectionalColor;
  uniform bool uUseLighting;
  out vec2 vTextureCoord;
  out vec3 vLightWeighting;
  out vec3 meVertexPosition;
  uniform vec3 u_lightWorldPosition;
  out vec3 v_normal;
  out vec3 v_surfaceToLight;
  out vec3 v_surfaceToView;
  out mat4 uMVMatrixINTER;
  out mat3 uNMatrixINTER;
  out mat4 uPMatrixINNTER;
  in vec4 specularColor;
  out vec4 vColor;
  out vec3 vNormal;
  out vec4 vPosition;
  out float vDist;
  uniform mat4 u_textureMatrix;
  out vec2 v_texcoord;
  out vec4 v_projectedTexcoord;
  uniform mat4 u_world;

  void main(void) {
    meVertexPosition = aVertexPosition;
    uMVMatrixINTER = uMVMatrix;
    uNMatrixINTER = uNMatrix;
    uPMatrixINNTER = uPMatrix;
    vColor = specularColor;
    vNormal = normalize(mat3(u_world) * vec3(aVertexNormal)); 
    vPosition =  uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vDist = gl_Position.w;
    v_normal = uNMatrix  *  vec3(aVertexNormal);
    vec3 surfaceWorldPosition = (uNMatrix * aVertexPosition).xyz;
    v_surfaceToLight = u_lightWorldPosition - surfaceWorldPosition;
    v_surfaceToView = (uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0)).xyz - surfaceWorldPosition;
    vec4 worldPosition =     vec4((uNMatrix * aVertexPosition).xyz, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = aTextureCoord;
   v_projectedTexcoord = u_textureMatrix * worldPosition;
    gl_Position   = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    if (!uUseLighting) {
      vLightWeighting = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    } else {
      vec3 transformedNormal          = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
      float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
      vLightWeighting                 = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
    }
  }`;
    scriptManager.LOAD(f, "cubeLightTex-shader-vs", "x-shader/x-vertex", "shaders")
}

Any suggestion?
If you wanna live demos of my library you can explore it here.
(Please support this Q - if you dont have idea just leave this page thnks)
